# Pulling value from sqlite3 DB in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm writing a script that inserts win/loss results into a sqlite3 database. I'm also trying to pull the win/loss count from said database table. However, I get an error that I can't convert from sqlite3 cursor object to a string to concatenate into my win message. I'm definitely doing something wrong here. Any help?

```
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO WINS(winner) VALUES('Computer')")
        numberWins = cur.execute("select count(*) from WINS where winner = 'Computer'")
        print("******************************\n" + numberWins + "Computer Wins\n******************************")
```

I get this error: **TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'sqlite3.Cursor' objects**

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [`.fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) or [`.fetchall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) on the query. That then returns either a tuple or a list of tuples. So you access the value with either `numberWins[0]` or `numberWins[0][0]`.

```
numberWins = cur.execute("select count(*) from WINS where winner = 'Computer'").fetchone()
print("************\n" + str(numberWins[0]) + "Computer Wins\n************")
```

Alternately you can use string formatting:

```
print("************\n {} Computer Wins\n************".format(numberWins[0]))
```